# Do I still need the separate gnome packages in 17.10.1?

Tags: apt, gnome, 17.10

I recently upgraded from 17.04 Gnome to 17.10.1 and I'm wondering if I still need the individual `-gnome` packages as well as the standard ones now that Ubuntu is using Gnome anyway.

For example, if I do `sudo apt list network*`, I get the following output:

```
network-config/artful,artful 0.2-2 all
network-manager/artful,now 1.8.4-1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
network-manager-config-connectivity-debian/artful,artful 1.8.4-1ubuntu3 all
network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu/artful,artful,now 1.8.4-1ubuntu3 all [installed]
network-manager-dev/artful 1.8.4-1ubuntu3 amd64
n**etwork-manager-gnome**/artful,now 1.8.4-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
network-manager-iodine/artful 1.2.0-1 amd64
network-manager-iodine-gnome/artful 1.2.0-1 amd64
network-manager-l2tp/artful 1.2.8-1 amd64
network-manager-l2tp-gnome/artful 1.2.8-1 amd64
network-manager-openconnect/artful 1.2.4-1 amd64
**network-manager-openconnect-gnome**/artful 1.2.4-1 amd64
network-manager-openvpn/artful,now 1.2.10-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
**network-manager-openvpn-gnome**/artful,now 1.2.10-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
network-manager-pptp/artful,now 1.2.4-4 amd64 [installed]
**network-manager-pptp-gnome**/artful,now 1.2.4-4 amd64 [installed]
network-manager-ssh/artful 1.2.6-1 amd64
**network-manager-ssh-gnome**/artful 1.2.6-1 amd64
network-manager-strongswan/artful 1.4.2-1 amd64
network-manager-vpnc/artful 1.2.4-4 amd64
**network-manager-vpnc-gnome**/artful 1.2.4-4 amd64
networking-mlnx-common/artful,artful 1:9.0.0~b1-1 all
networking-mlnx-eswitchd/artful,artful 1:9.0.0~b1-1 all
```

You can see in the results `network-manager` and `network-manager-gnome`. I'm wondering if I still need the `-gnome` package or if I can uninstall it?

I was going to try removing it anyway to see what happened but `apt` threatened to remove `ubuntu-desktop`.

```
baa@baa-PC:~$ sudo apt remove network-manager-gnome
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gnome-control-center-faces libwhoopsie-preferences0 whoopsie-preferences
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  **gnome-control-center network-manager-gnome ubuntu-desktop**
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 3 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 6,489 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Comment: Leave them;  I have exactly the same packages installed, even though I installed 17.10 from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific example, the `network-manager` package provides the system service, and `network-manager-gnome` provides the panel applet/indicator, and connection editing application.

You may still need it to edit VPN or Wireless configurations, for example, though I don't think the applet is used with gnome-shell.